# Fill in the month date based on the date modified

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to generate additional column named month and create additional record to fill the month for the whole year.

This example of the original data

```
ID   | DateModified
---- | ------------
123  | 01-01-2020
123  | 11-05-2020
```

This is the desired outcome

```
ID  | DateModified | Month
--- | ------------ | -----
123 | 01-01-2020   | Jan
123 | 01-01-2020   | Feb
123 | 01-01-2020   | March
123 | 01-01-2020   | April
123 | 11-05-2020   | May
123 | 11-05-2020   | June
123 | 11-05-2020   | July
123 | 11-05-2020   | August
123 | 11-05-2020   | September
123 | 11-05-2020   | October
123 | 11-05-2020   | November
123 | 11-05-2020   | December
```

Please advise how to archive these results.

Comment: Please tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Could you please update your question to more details? Do you want to add more column `Month` based on `DateModified`? Because your sample data is quite clearly @serenityendy

Comment: I am using MS SQL, sorry, this is my first post.

Comment: Yes, trying to create a new column named "Month" and additional record that does shows JAn to Dec.

Comment: What if there is no January DateModified? What if there are two DateModified in the same month?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) to achieve it

```
UPDATE a
SET a.DateModified = DATEADD(MONTH, b.Month_Value, a.DateModified )   
FROM Your_Table a
INNER JOIN MonthValue_AccordingTo_MonthTextTable b ON a.Month = b.Month_Text
```

Comment: An UPDATE will not generate new rows

Comment: It seems that the question is not quite clearly, sir.

Comment: I had added more details but update will not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer. I hope this works for you... notice that it works for dates within the same year, that not span to the next.

```
CREATE TABLE wrk(
    id int,
    DateModified datetime
)
GO

INSERT INTO wrk values(123, '20200101')
INSERT INTO wrk values(123, '20200511')
GO

WITH
    months as(
        SELECT 1  AS month_idx, 'jan' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 2  AS month_idx, 'feb' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 3  AS month_idx, 'mar' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 4  AS month_idx, 'apr' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 5  AS month_idx, 'may' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 6  AS month_idx, 'jun' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 7  AS month_idx, 'jul' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 8  AS month_idx, 'aug' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 9  AS month_idx, 'sep' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 10 AS month_idx, 'oct' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 11 AS month_idx, 'nov' AS month_key UNION ALL
        SELECT 12 AS month_idx, 'dec' AS month_key
    ),
    w as(
        SELECT
            w.id, w.DateModified,
            --
            datepart(month, w.DateModified) AS MonthModifiedFrom,
            --
            isnull(
                datepart(
                    month,
                    min(w_next.DateModified)
                ) - 1,
                12 /* December */
            ) AS MonthModifiedTo
        FROM
            wrk w
                LEFT OUTER JOIN wrk w_next
                ON(
                        w_next.id = w.id
                    AND w_next.DateModified > w.DateModified
                )
        GROUP BY w.id, w.DateModified
    )
SELECT
    w.id, w.DateModified, m.month_key
FROM
    w
        INNER JOIN months m
        ON m.month_idx BETWEEN w.MonthModifiedFrom AND w.MonthModifiedTo
```

Comment: Almost there. But, the first date which is 2020-01-01 it populate from feb to Dec. Is there a way to restrict to populate up until may. Thank you